# LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync kills win32 app

Tags: c#, process, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

Hi I have below code to launch a Win32 app from UWP app:

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

I find if my Win32 app is already launched, the above code kills my Win32 app. Is there a way I know this launch fails so I can relaunch it?

Or I have to check before I call the above code if the Win32 is running, I shouldn't launch by `LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync`? I cannot check running process in the UWP apps to see whether Win32 app is running, whether I can wait for a bit and check the app service connection is ready, otherwise I should relaunch again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the API doesn't kill your Win32 app if it's already running. It will launch a second instance.

Here is my test project to verify it works correctly: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnY5PmDGomMo0V1jB7w

If in your case the existing Win32 app instance terminates, it is likely because some of your code/logic isn't handling multiple instances correctly.

Comment: My Win32 app has to be a single instance app. Is that the reason it was killed?

Comment: And I use the app connection service to let the UWP talk to the wpf app, if wpf is not single instance app, whether the app connection service communication still works between them?

Comment: What is the best practice to make sure the launch Win32 app successfully and app connection service is ready to use, and if launch fails or connection not ready yet, what is the best practice to recover?

Comment: You need to implement a singleton pattern, something like this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx